# using declaration in class definition

Tags: c++, c++11

I found that 'using' keyword can be used in class definition.
according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration, its used for member function is as follows:

> If the name is the name of an overloaded member function of the base
>   class, all base class member functions with that name are introduced.
>   If the derived class already has a member with the same name,
>   parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member hides or
>   overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member that is introduced from
>   the base class.

an example code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    virtual void f(int) { std::cout << "B::f\n"; }
    void g(char)        { std::cout << "B::g\n"; }
    void h(int)         { std::cout << "B::h\n"; }
 protected:
    int m; // B::m is protected
    typedef int value_type;
};

struct D : B {
    using B::m; // D::m is public
    using B::value_type; // D::value_type is public

    using B::f;
    void f(int) { std::cout << "D::f\n"; } // D::f(int) overrides     B::f(int)
    using B::g;
    void g(int) { std::cout << "D::g\n"; } // both g(int) and g(char) are visible
                                       // as members of D
    using B::h;
    void h(int) { std::cout << "D::h\n"; } // D::h(int) hides B::h(int)
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    B& b = d;

//    b.m = 2; // error, B::m is protected
    d.m = 1; // protected B::m is accessible as public D::m
    b.f(1); // calls derived f()
    d.f(1); // calls derived f()
    d.g(1); // calls derived g(int)
    d.g('a'); // calls base g(char)
    b.h(1); // calls base h()
    d.h(1); // calls derived h()
}
```

From the above code, I am not sure what is the difference, for instance

```
using B::f;
void f(int)
```

and

```
virtual void f(int)
```

Is there definite difference for using 'using' keyword in order to override class member function?

Comment: This actually has very little to do with virtual functions.    Look up the "hiding rule" for what this is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording from that article is unfortunate. They tried to fix it with the parenthetical, but…

**This has nothing to do with virtual function overriding.**

The two examples you give are different and unrelated.

One brings the base class `f` into scope, then chucks that away and introduces a new `D::f` function. (This will not be `virtual` unless `B::f` already was, per the normal rules).

The other declares a `virtual` `D::f`.